# Sorting Currency in Bootstrap Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, sorting, bootstrap-table

I want to add the currency sign to my number while making the value remain sortable as a number in my Bootstrap Table (line 30-34; column 4 in the table):

```
for (var p=0; p<variable_data.length; p++){
    try{
        variable_data[p]["4"] = "$" + Math.round(variable_data[p]["4"])
    } catch(e){ }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mademoiselletse/s0d1xgzt/

The values with the '$' attached are sorted as strings instead of numbers.  All the currency sorting problems I found online pertain to the DataTable and tablesorter() plugins.  Is there a quicker fix to the problem than installing more jQuery plugins?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Check the custom example [here](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html#custom-sort-table)

You need to send a `data-sorter function` that removes the $ from your string and then compares it as numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I inputted the following in HTML line 34: `<th data-field="4" data-sorter="priceSorter" data-sortable="true" data-align="center" data-valign="middle">Leasehackr<br>Estimate </th>` and the `priceSorter` script at the end of my javascript (line 246-252) but the table is not sorting correctly. Could you give me some pointers on what I might have done wrong? 
http://jsfiddle.net/mademoiselletse/s0d1xgzt/3/

Comment: in the last link you supplied, your sorting works on the last 2 columns, am I wrong ?

Comment: Unfortunately the link you referenced is now 404. I have a sorter function firing, but documentation on how to return the compared values within is lacking.

Comment: This is a good example of why link-only answers are bad. Example should be in the answer itself. See [your answer is in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problems and finally looked at the source code of the custom sorter example from their actual website: http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#options/custom-sort.html

To begin with, when defining the column containing currency/money/dollar values add a reference for **sorter** to whatever javascript function you want to use. Here's what my currency column definition looks like:

```
[
    "field" => "total",
    "title" => "Total",
    "sortable" => true,
    "sorter" => "totalCurrencySort"
]
```

After that you'll want to create that javascript function which executes when that particular column is sorted. Here we define **totalCurrencySort** which can take 4 parameters, however only the first two are needed.

```
function totalCurrencySort(a, b, rowA, rowB) {  
    a = +a.substring(1); // remove $
    b = +b.substring(1);
    if (a > b) return 1;
    if (a < b) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

To do a proper comparison the "$" is stripped—as desired—and a numerical evaluation determines the proper sort state between the two values and returns accordingly. The rowN reference provides the full dataset of the row in case your custom sorting logic requires more complicated calculations using other data from within the row.

Answer (score 0):

I'm too new to comment on Art's post, but wanted to add notes for what worked for me. The totalCurrencySort function in Art's post worked for me. In the table header, I had the attribute as data-sorter (as opposed to just sorter).

```
function totalCurrencySorter(a, b, rowA, rowB) {
a = +a.substring(1);  // remove $
b = +b.substring(1);
if (a > b) return 1;
if (a < b) return -1;
return 0;
}

function totalCurrencyFormatter(data) {
var field = this.field
return '$' + data.map(function (row) {
return +row[field].substring(1)
}).reduce(function (sum, i) {
return sum + i;
}, 0)
}
```

For the HTML table, I had the heading generally like this:

```
<thead>
<tr>
<th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">ID</th>
<th data-field="exp_date" data-sortable="true">Date</th>
<th data-field="amount" data-sortable="true" formatter="totalCurrencyFormatter" data-sorter="totalCurrencySorter">Amount</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Art and OptimisticToaster's answers, I'm also too new to comment, so my take on the problem is this:

```
function totalCurrencySort(a, b, rowA, rowB) {  
    
    a = Number(a.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g,""));
    b = Number(b.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g,""));
    
    if (a > b) return 1;
    if (a < b) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

I was working with numbers formatted as so £1,000.50 so stripping any non-numeric allows the sort to work whatever format the figure is using.